# Eloquent provider inside composer package in vendor not auto-loading on a dev environment

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, composer-php

I'm developing a composer package. I've done this before, but I don't know why at this point I'm not getting composer to figure out about my file in the package when building auto-loading.

The purpose of the package is to add a listener in Laravel's Eloquent to log queries to a file. However, for this I need to make the system execute a provider boot method right at the beginning of the system load.

The idea is for the package to be installed only in development environment, to facilitate query improvement without the danger of uploading unnecessary code to production. I've tried some variations, making use of `"classmap"`, `"file"` and others, all within `"autoload-dev"` but all without success.

I have the perception that in addition to not discovering the files, the `providers` item (which would actualy make it to load the provider) would also be incorrect, but I couldn't get to this point to validate.

My environment in the project where I'm testing the package installation is set to `APP_ENV=local`.

Below is the latest version of the attempted change I made to the `composer.json` file inside the package, directly in the vendor directory of the test project. The package being installed is available at https://github.com/rstriquer/eloquent-logger/tree/bc32616a0dcf727e7385059ef523c3dcb41881fa (link to v1.0.0-rc2 tag)

```json
{
  "name": "rstriquer/eloquent-logger",
  "description": "Write SQL queries to a file into Laravel \"storage/logs\" directory.",
  "keywords": ["laravel", "eloquent", "logger", "debugger", "laravel-dev"],
  "license": "MIT",
  "support": {
      "issues": "https://github.com/rstriquer/eloquent-logger/issues",
      "source": "https://github.com/rstriquer/eloquent-logger"
  },
  "authors": [
      {
          "name": "Ricardo Soares",
          "email": "rstriquer@gmail.com"
      }
  ],
  "require": {
      "php": ">7.0",
      "laravel/framework": ">8.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {
      "laravel/pint": "^1.1.1",
      "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
      "phpstan/phpstan": "^1.4.6",
      "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.23",
      "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.2"
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
      "classmap": [
        "vendor/rstriquer/eloquent-logger/src/Adapters/Laravel/DatabaseServiceProvider.php"
      ],
      "psr-4": {
        "RStriquer\\EloquentLogger\\Adapters\\Laravel": "src/Adapters/Laravel",
        "RStriquer\\EloquentLogger\\Tests\\Unit\\": "tests/Unit"
      }
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true,
  "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
          "RStriquer\\EloquentLogger\\": "src/"
      }
  },
  "config": {
      "preferred-install": "prod",
      "sort-packages": true
  },
  "extra": {
      "laravel": {
          "providers": [
              "RStriquer\\EloquentLogger\\Adapters\\Laravel\\DatabaseServiceProvider"
          ]
      }
  },
  "scripts": {
      "lint": "pint -v",
      "test:lint": "pint --test -v",
      "test:types": "phpstan analyse --ansi",
      "test:unit": "phpunit --colors=always",
      "test": [
          "@test:lint",
          "@test:types",
          "@test:unit"
      ]
  }
}
```

PS: Real thanks in advance to everyone who makes the effort to help. I am much obliged!

Answer (score 1):

I identified what was going on.

I don't know if I can call it a bug, I'll study a little more and if that's the case, open an issue on the composer project's github for discussion later, but here are my findings.

What was happening is that I was doing installation tests with a beta version of the package, so it wasn't loading. I believe that as the package was being loaded from a github repository it was not able to perform an autoloading, even in the development environment. Maybe because of some security restriction.

To solve it I simply published the package on getcomposer.com and the problem was resolved.

Comment: If you want to test your development package not yet released on packagist, the global composer package registry, add your local repository within the composer environment during the installation test. That is you can test a versioned release (alternatively tagged) of the package before releasing it. This can be useful in your case as you want to try it out how it would behave if installed in another project. IMHO this is far away from a bug in Composer, but documented on how repositories (incl. packagist) work for Composer (just FYI).

Comment: Complementary to what @hakre just said: It would have been enough for me to have added the directory where the package is installed to the ```URL``` item in the ```repository``` item of the ```composer.json``` project in which the test was being carried out (as illustrated below) and this would cause the project to be loaded from the local repository and would not have the impediment I mentioned.
```"repositories": [{"type": "path", "url": "/home/user/src/package"}]```